# Creating a budgeting expense sheet - Adding a row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have created a button to insert a row. Each row I add says "Insert expense here.

The problem is that when I click the button and insert the row, the row new row only populates where it says B7. If I were to delete "test" in B7 leave it blank, and then click the button it would get generated under B5 where it says expenses.

I just want a new row to be added so I can list my expenses accordingly. I also attached a screenshot

Here is my code in VBA below:

```vb
    Sub Button17_Click()
   

    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Insert An Expense…"

    End Sub
```

"Insert An Expense..." only gets added below the cell that has "test" populated. If the cell is blank, "Insert an Expense" gets populated above the cell that says "expenses"

[image: "Insert An Expense..." only gets added below the cell that has "test" populated. If the cell is blank, "Insert an Expense" gets populated above the cell that says "expenses"]

Comment: This is probably going to require VBA. Specifically hooking into the [`SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event to detect the cell selection change, verify it's a cell you care about, clear that cell out and update the next row with that `Insert an expense` text. Honestly, I would rather just teach someone how to use excel.

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to think that as well because of how difficult it is to do this. I have been trying to figure this out for the last three days.

Comment: Is the problem that a line is being inserted above the last line, but you want a new line inserted below the last populated line?

Comment: It's populating above the value. In the screenshot, the value is "test" I want it to populate when there is no value and it goes down the spreadsheet, creating a list where I will then manually change it from "Insert an Expense" to Rent, Credit Card, Mortgage, etc

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want it to be added at the end of the current list (therefore if you were to click the button in the situation you are presenting the new line would appear under the "test" line). Try this code:

```
 Sub Button17_Click()
    
    Dim RngNewExpense As Range
    Dim DblTop As Double
    
    Set RngNewExpense = Range("B:B")
    DblTop = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match("Expenses", RngNewExpense, 0) + 2
    
    Set RngNewExpense = RngNewExpense.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    If RngNewExpense.Row < DblTop Then
        
        Set RngNewExpense = Cells(DblTop, RngNewExpense.Column)
        
    End If
    
    RngNewExpense.EntireRow.Insert
    
    RngNewExpense.Offset(-1, 0).Formula = "Insert An Expense…"
    
End Sub
```

I've left the setting of RngNewExpense as hardcoded while DblTop has a more dynamic approach. You can choose to change them accordingly to your need. I've also used a longer code than strictly necessary for legibility's sake.

Comment: Looks like its working! Thank you so much. I appreciate your patience. I have never coded in VBA

Answer (score 0):

### Insert a New Row Below the Last Cell...

... starting with a given cell.

- `Insert` always inserts above.
- You forgot to use `Offset`. `.End(xlUp)` will reference the last non-empty cell so your code will insert above it. By appending `.Offset(1)` you would have solved the first issue.
- But there is a 2nd issue, which is that the `Expenses` cell is above the `Forecast` cells leaving an empty cell below it so when there were no data below, it would have inserted a row between those two cells. To easily deal with this, you could either populate the cell below with `Expenses` instead, or populate it with `=""`. Then `End(xlUp).Offset(1)` would always work.
- BTW, `Select` and any flavor of `Active` is best avoided in VBA because it slows down your code (use the search box at the top of this page and read about it, maybe start with [this legendary post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).).
- Here's a bit different approach.

```vb
Sub Button17_Click()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "B7"
    Const InsertString As String = "Insert An Expense…"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim RowOffset As Long

    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
        RowOffset = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowOffset < 0 Then RowOffset = 0
        With .Offset(RowOffset)
            .EntireRow.Insert
            .Offset(-1).Value = InsertString
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```